# Code was working but now doesn't work all of a sudden - Dataframe issues

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am not very proficient at python but my aim was to extract data from my share dealing website with the intention of analysis further down the line. The below code worked for me once and now i get an error about arrays not being the same length but they already are. this literally worked for me with no modification of the code but now suddenly its not working.

Code and error below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)


r = requests.get("https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/a")
soup = bs(r.content, features = "lxml")
a = soup.find('ul', {'class':'list-unstyled list-indent'}).find_all("strong")

r3 = requests.get("https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/b")
soup = bs(r3.content, features = "lxml")
b = soup.find('ul', {'class':'list-unstyled list-indent'}).find_all("strong")

r5 = requests.get("https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/c")
soup = bs(r5.content, features = "lxml")
c  = soup.find('ul', {'class':'list-unstyled list-indent'}).find_all("strong")


header  = a + b + c

r1 = requests.get("https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/a")
soup = bs(r1.content, features = "lxml")
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'list-unstyled list-indent'}).find_all("a", href=True)]

r4 = requests.get("https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/b")
soup = bs(r4.content, features = "lxml")
links1 = [a['href'] for a in soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'list-unstyled list-indent'}).find_all("a", href=True)]

r6 = requests.get("https://www.somewebsite.co.uk/shares/shares-search-results/c")
soup = bs(r6.content, features = "lxml")
links2 = [a['href'] for a in soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'list-unstyled list-indent'}).find_all("a", href=True)]

column2 = links + links1 + links2

com_list = []
for b in header[0:]:
    result = b.text.strip()
    com_list.append(result)

com_com = pd.DataFrame({'COMPANY': com_list, 'LINKS': column2})
print(com_com)
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hls.py", line 42, in <module>
    com_com = pd.DataFrame({'COMPANY': com_list, 'LINKS': column2})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 392, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 212, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 51, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 317, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you have different number of elements in ***com_list*** and ***column2***. They must be same.

check

> len(com_list) == len(column2)

Comment: When i LEN header and column2 they return the same number.